# How to scrape hrefs disguised with unicode (e.g \u003ca href=\)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape relative paths contained in hrefs but they arent showing up in anything but the main soup pull. If I try to pull hrefs or links specifically, the ones I'm looking to scrape just don't show up but I know they are there.

```
\u003ca href=\"/model/ford-1200\"
\u003ca href=\"/model/ford-1300\"
\u003ca href=\"/model/ford-1400\"
```

Is there a way to get to create a list of the 20 or so "u003ca href"s on the page? I'm looking for just the part in the quotes (e.g. /model/ford-1200, /model/ford-1300, /model/ford-1400), collected into a list.

Is this a use-case where I'm going to need to sack up and learn javascript scraping?

Comment: is that how the `HTML` presented within the source page?

Comment: that's exactly what it looks like *where it appears*, there is other content between it though

Comment: so edit your question and post the HTML as is it. you can share the url better

Comment: in beautifulsoup, you use re and then parse it out. if it's in javascript, something like this should pull it out. soup.find_all(string=compile('/model/'). then as you loop through, you can use .split() or regex to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Got it. I'll read up on regex and give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue wasn't solved through addressing the unicode or using re -- it was an issue with the content not loading enough to be scraped. I solved this through using selenium which allowed me to scrape the hrefs as I normally would.